# Iterating JavaScript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my object that I want to parse through:

```
my.test = [{"Customer":
    {
        "id":"123",
        "Name":"john"
    }
}]
```

I have this already:

```
$.each(Cmy.test, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value.Customer, function(innerIndex, innerValue) {
        alert('File ' + innerValue.id + ' in customer ' + index);
    });
});
```

But my `alert()` shows `undefined` for value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON looks a little incomplete it seems its missing a }] at the end

Comment: Surely "$.each(Cmy.test..." is a typo and is actually "$.each(my.test..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my.test = [{"Customer":
{
"id":"123",
"Name":"john",
}
```

should be

```
my.test = [{"Customer": {
  "id":"123",
  "Name":"john"
}}];
```

then iterate like this:

```
$.each(my.test, function(index) {
  alert('File ' + my.test[index].Customer.id + ' in customer ' + index);
});
```

At least that's what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Check brace count on object literal.

Comment: Also, [trailing comma of death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/) is lurking...

Answer (score 2):

See [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) -- when iterating over "non-array" objects the callback is passed `(key, value)`.

For instance, in the above example the callback may be passed a `key` of "id" and a `value` of "123". As a result, `"123".id` (`innerValue.id`) is most likely nonsensical as it will evaluate to undefined.

The outer-loop is okay because `(index, value)` is passed in the callback for arrays. In this case the value is `{Customer: ...}`.

Happy coding.